# Postgres - How to perform a LIKE query on a JSONB field?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a jsonb field called `passengers`, with the following structure:

**note that persons is an array**

```
{
    "adults": {
        "count": 2,
        "persons": [
            {
                "age": 45,
                "name": "Prof. Kyleigh Walsh II",
                "birth_date": "01-01-1975"
            },
            {
                "age": 42,
                "name": "Milford Wiza",
                "birth_date": "02-02-1978"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How may I perform a query against the name field of this JSONB? For example, to select all rows which match the name field `Prof`?

Here's my rudimentary attempt:

```
SELECT passengers from opportunities
WHERE 'passengers->adults' != NULL
AND 'passengers->adults->persons->name' LIKE '%Prof';
```

This returns 0 rows, but as you can see I have one row with the name `Prof. Kyleigh Walsh II`

Comment: I'm using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This: `'passengers->adults->persons->name' LIKE '%Prof';` checks if the string `'passengers->adults->persons->name'` ends with `Prof`.

Each key for the JSON operator needs to be a separate element, and the column name must not be enclosed in single quotes. So `'passengers->adults->persons->name'` needs to be `passengers -> 'adults' -> 'persons' -> 'name'`

The `->` operator returns a `jsonb` value, you want a `text` value, so the last operator should be `->>`

Also `!= null` does not work, you need to use `is not null`.

```
SELECT passengers 
from opportunities
WHERE passengers -> 'adults' is not NULL
 AND  passengers -> 'adults' -> 'persons' ->> 'name' LIKE 'Prof%';
```

The `is not null` condition isn't really necessary, because that is implied with the second condition. The second condition could be simplified to:

```
SELECT passengers 
from opportunities
WHERE passengers #>> '{adults,persons,name}' LIKE 'Prof%';
```

---

But as `persons` is an array, the above wouldn't work and you need to use a different approach.

With Postgres 9.6 you will need a sub-query to unnest the array elements (and thus iterate over each one).

```
SELECT passengers 
from opportunities
WHERE exists (select * 
              from jsonb_array_elements(passengers -> 'adults' -> 'persons') as p(person)
              where p.person ->> 'name' LIKE 'Prof%');
```

To match a string at the beginning with LIKE, the wildcard needs to be at the end. `'%Prof'` would match `'Some Prof'` but not `'Prof. Kyleigh Walsh II'`

---

With Postgres 12, you could use a [SQL/JSON Path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression:

```
SELECT passengers 
from opportunities
WHERE passengers @? '$.adults.persons[*] ? (@.name like_regex "Prof.*")'
```

Comment: Does this mean Postgres knows that `persons` is an array, and will it perform the query on each index of the array, or just the first?

Comment: Yes true I did. I'm using Postgres 9.6 btw.

Comment: Would it also be possible to order by a field in the `persons` array? Like order by name ASC?